# ScalaTest test if sequence is sorted

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scalatest

Why doesn't this compile with ScalaTest 2.0.M5b?

```
import org.scalatest.matchers.MatchResult
import org.scalatest.matchers.BeMatcher
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers._

def sorted[T <% Ordered[T]] = new BeMatcher[Seq[T]] {
  override def apply(s: Seq[T]) =
    MatchResult(
        s match {
          case Seq(h, t@_*) => s.zip(t).forall{ case (x,y) => x < y }
          case _ => true
        },
        s + " was not sorted",
        s + " was sorted")
}

val s = Seq(1, 2, 3)
s should be (sorted[Int])
```

This is the error I get:

```
overloaded method value should with alternatives: (beWord: NewCollectionsSpec.this.BeWord)NewCollectionsSpec.this.ResultOfBeWordForAnyRef[scala.collection.GenSeq[Int]] <and> (notWord: 
 NewCollectionsSpec.this.NotWord)NewCollectionsSpec.this.ResultOfNotWordForAnyRef[scala.collection.GenSeq[Int]] <and> (haveWord: 
 NewCollectionsSpec.this.HaveWord)NewCollectionsSpec.this.ResultOfHaveWordForSeq[Int] <and> (rightMatcher: org.scalatest.matchers.Matcher[scala.collection.GenSeq[Int]])Unit cannot be applied to 
 (org.scalatest.matchers.Matcher[Seq[Int]])
```

Comment: This compiles: `convertToAnyRefShouldWrapper(s) should be (sorted[Int])`

Comment: Are you sure? This doesn't compiles too. May be it depends on ScalaTest version.

Comment: I updated the code in the question to fix the view bound bug, sorry about that.

Comment: imports for BeMatcher, MatchResult would be handy to copy/paste them in the REPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s: Seq[Int]` was implicitly converted to `SeqShouldWrapper[GenSeq[Int]]`. It has no `should` alternative compatible with `Matcher[Seq[Int]]`. But it has `def should(rightMatcher: Matcher[GenSeq[T]])`. So, if you change you matcher type constraints, everything will compile:

```
def sorted[T <% Ordered[T]] = new BeMatcher[GenSeq[T]] {
  def apply(s: GenSeq[T]) =
    MatchResult(
      s match {
        case Seq(h, t@_*) => s.zip(t).forall {
          case (x, y) => x < y
        }
        case _ => true
      },
      s + " was not sorted",
      s + " was sorted")
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Scalatest already provides just such a matcher:

```
seq shouldBe sorted
```

Note that the similar-looking code

```
seq should be sorted
```

does not compile.